# apply texture2d from one object to another object in different scene

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i have a script that takes a picture using the devices camera. it applies the texture to the gameobject which is a cube. now how do i go about applying this texture that has been applied to this cube, to another cube in a different scene.

this is the code below for my camerascript:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using CameraShot;

public class CameraShotExample : MonoBehaviour {

string log = "";
void OnEnable()
{

    CameraShotEventListener.onImageSaved += OnImageSaved;
    CameraShotEventListener.onImageLoad += OnImageLoad;
    CameraShotEventListener.onVideoSaved += OnVideoSaved;
    CameraShotEventListener.onError += OnError;
    CameraShotEventListener.onCancel += OnCancel;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    CameraShotEventListener.onImageSaved -= OnImageSaved;
    CameraShotEventListener.onImageLoad -= OnImageLoad;
    CameraShotEventListener.onVideoSaved -= OnVideoSaved;
    CameraShotEventListener.onError -= OnError;
    CameraShotEventListener.onCancel -= OnCancel;
}

void OnImageSaved(string path, ImageOrientation orientation)
{
    log += "\nImage Saved to gallery, path : " + path + ", orientation : " +  orientation;
}

void OnImageLoad(string path,Texture2D tex, ImageOrientation orientation)
{
    GameObject.Find("Cube").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    log += "\nImage Saved to gallery, loaded :" + path + ", orientation : " + orientation;

}

void OnVideoSaved(string path)
{
    Debug.Log ("Video Saved at path : "+path);
    log += "\nVideo Saved at path :" + path;
}

void OnError(string errorMsg)
{
    Debug.Log ("Error : "+errorMsg);
    log += "\nError : "+errorMsg;
}

void OnCancel()
{
    Debug.Log ("OnCancel");
    log += "\nOnCancel";
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.Label (log);
    float btnWidth = 150;
    float btnHeight = 50;
    float y = Screen.height/2-btnHeight/2 - 50;
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-btnWidth/2,y,btnWidth,btnHeight),"Capture Image"))
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidCameraShot.LaunchCameraForImageCapture(false); 
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        IOSCameraShot.LaunchCameraForImageCapture(true);// capture and crop
        #endif
    }

    y += 100;
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-btnWidth/2,y,btnWidth,btnHeight),"Get Texture"))
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidCameraShot.GetTexture2DFromCamera(false);
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        IOSCameraShot.GetTexture2DFromCamera(true);// capture and crop
        #endif
    }

    y += 100;
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-btnWidth/2,y,btnWidth,btnHeight),"Record Video"))
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidCameraShot.LaunchCameraForVideoCapture(0);
        //AndroidCameraShot.LaunchCameraForVideoCapture(10);// record for 10 seconds
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        IOSCameraShot.LaunchCameraForVideoCapture(0); // record for unlimited time
        //IOSCameraShot.LaunchCameraForVideoCapture(10); // record for 10 sec
        #endif

        GlobalData.userPhoto = Texture2D;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static field like `public static Texture2D myTexture;` and when you load it in your `OnImageLoad` you can add the value to the static field :

```
void OnImageLoad(string path,Texture2D tex, ImageOrientation orientation)
{
    GameObject.Find("Cube").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    log += "\nImage Saved to gallery, loaded :" + path + ", orientation : " + orientation;

    myTexture = tex;
}
```

Then you can easily access it from any script by doing:

```
CameraShotExample.myTexture
```

Comment: cheers for some reason i am getting an error, im pretty new to unity. the error i am getting is error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. how can i resolve this?

Comment: when i input CameraShotExample.myTexture in my script for my other cube

Comment: @U53R okay but what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: apply the texture to another cube in another scene, im kinda confused can you point me in the right direction please

Comment: @U53R can you show the full line where there's the error?

Comment: im getting a different error now:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object this is my code below:

Comment: public class example : MonoBehaviour {

 public static example instance;

 GameObject cube;

 void Awake () {
 }

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

  cube.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = CameraShotExample.myTexture;
   
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }


}

Comment: @U53R it's probably because it is getting called before you applied the texture in the other script.

Comment: ive ran it on my phone applied the texture on the first cube successfully, but still no luck with it being applied to the other cube in the other scene. kinda stuck here

Comment: @U53R Are you sure your texture is being initialized before trying to apply it to the other one. Because you've put it in the `Awake()` the moment that script exist in a scene it will call that function.

Comment: im sure it is. im removed the void awake function but no luck still. any idea?